# How can I state and display documentation related to constant values in a proper way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, yard

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I am trying to use YARD 0.7.4. I would like to document constant values, so in my class I state this:

```
# [Fixnum] Test constant documentation.
TEST_CONSTANT = 1
```

but the HTML output after I run the `yardoc` (or `yard doc`) command is the following:

[image]

In the above image is shown that the HTML documentation is not good rendered/generated, at least not as I would expect. I read the [YAML documentation](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/0.7.4/file/docs/GettingStarted.md) but I still have some problem on that: **how can I better state and display documentation related to constant values?**

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this problem and google returned me this unanswered post. I found the answer by Loren Segal (creator of Yard) in another forum: [link_to_forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/yardoc/kw5FmhDNFQk). For completeness reasons I add this for people that run into the same problem:

You document it the same way you document any other object. Just put comments above the constant.

```
# Documentation here
TEST_CONSTANT = 1
```

Note though that at least for me the resulting formatting looks a bit strange. It first formats the name of the constant, then shows the description and then the values. I would expect first the description, followed by the name and values.